# Custom notification sound not playing iOS objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to get a `localNotification` to play a custom sound but I just cannot get it to work. I have declared it and double check the file type but it just will not work. The file is called `Alarm Clock.caf` and it's added to the file and is 29.4 seconds long, so fits the guidelines. And this is the `localNotification` code:

```
-(void) scheduleLocalNotificationWithDate:(NSDate *)fireDate {
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    notification.fireDate  = fireDate;
    notification.alertBody = @"Hello!";
    notification.soundName =  @"Alarm-Clock.caf";
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: notification];
```

How do I get it to play?

Thanks

Comment: is Alarm Clock.caf file added to your project ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sometimes there is a glitch with stops it from working properly if its too long even if it's under the limit. Try shortening it and renaming it something with no spaces or capital letters like `notifsound`. Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

```
 UILocalNotification *local = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
local.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
// set notification details
local.alertBody = @"Alarm!";
local.soundName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tring.caf"];
local.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:210]; //time in seconds
```

This is an example.

Use Terminal to make caf file from `mp4/wav`

`afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@44100 -c 1 your.wav your.caf`

Also make sure select `your.caf`file and checked Target Membership

[image]

Comment: it is `.caf` and is added to the right target membership. anything else i shld do?

Comment: try changing the file name and duration of file from 29 to some 15.

Comment: one more doubt local notification doesn't play sound when app is running.if app is in background then it will play